# Execute a task (line of code) at a particular time of the day

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, data-connections

I am trying to enable/disable mobile data at specific time of the day. This is what I have so far:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Calendar objCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    objCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
    objCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    objCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    //
    // Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    // intent.setAction("com.sang.mobiledata.ACTION");
    //
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(
     this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)
     this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, objCal.getTimeInMillis(),
     AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Basically, I would like to turn off the data connection say at 10pm. I know this will be achieved by this line:

```
objNetwork.setMobileDataEnabled(getBaseContext(), false);
```

and again turn it on at say 6am

```
objNetwork.setMobileDataEnabled(getBaseContext(), true);
```

I just dont know how (and where) to give that condition.

EDIT:

```
public class Network {

public void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {

    try {
        ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = ConnectivityManager.class
                .getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);

        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(conman, enabled);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

EDIT 2 (complete code):

ConnBroadCastReceiver.java

```
public class ConnBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String CONN_ACTION = "com.sang.mobiledata.IntentAction.RECEIVE_CONN_UPDATE";
Network objNetwork = new Network();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(CONN_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        boolean enableConn = intent.getBooleanExtra("FLAG_KEY", false);
        objNetwork.setMobileDataEnabled(context, enableConn);
    }
 }
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    triggerEnable(true, 6);
    triggerEnable(false, 22);
}

private void triggerEnable(boolean enableData, int hourInDay) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (enableData) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourInDay);
    } else {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourInDay);
    }
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.sang.mobiledata.IntentAction.RECEIVE_CONN_UPDATE");
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("FLAG_KEY", enableData);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, broadcastIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
}
```

Network.java

```
 public class Network {

public void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {

    try {
        ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = ConnectivityManager.class
                .getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);

        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
          setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(conman, enabled);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
```

manifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name="com.sang.mobiledata.ConnBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sang.mobiledata.IntentAction.RECEIVE_CONN_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried to toggle data connection - assuming above will work if you provide proper permissions (if any is supposed to have) and above code doesn't make use of reflection as I have seen other people are shooting themselves in the foot ... 
However, if you intend to open an application activity at a specific time, then I would say that's a bad practice at least from user experience point of view. Instead of doing that, you could send a broadcast message through [`PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29). 
 
That being said:

1. Construct an intent with an action of your own, add a boolean flag inside that is meaningfull (true to enable connectivity, false otherwise).
2. Pass that intent to your `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`
3. Create a `BroadcastReceiver` in your class, register it in the Manifest and handle properly that action. Something like:

The BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class ConnBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String CONN_ACTION = "my_package_name.IntentAction.RECEIVE_CONN_UPDATE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(CONN_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            boolean enableConn = intent.getBooleanExtra("FLAG_KEY", false);
            objNetwork.setMobileDataEnabled(context, enableConn);
        }
    }
}
```

register it in the Manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="my_package_name.ConnBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="my_package_name.IntentAction.RECEIVE_CONN_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and trigger the broadcast from your above code:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("my_package_name.IntentAction.RECEIVE_CONN_UPDATE");
broadcastIntent.putExtra("FLAG_KEY", enableData);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, objCal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

**EDIT** Above `onCreate` can be re-writen to:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    triggerEnable(true, 6);
    triggerEnable(false, 22);
}

private void triggerEnable(boolean enableData, int hourInDay) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (enableData) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourInDay);
    } else {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourInDay);
    }
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("my_package_name.IntentAction.RECEIVE_CONN_UPDATE");
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("FLAG_KEY", enableData);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, broadcastIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
}
```

Comment: while all that you said sounds perfect and awesome, I really don't know how to do that... Also, please see my edit as am not very sure if it makes use of reflection or not.

Comment: Yes, that makes use of reflection. It's generally a bad idea (repeat, generally), as private API is not supposed to be called by apps for specific reasons. In this case: the app is enabling data connectivity, the user will pay from it. So your app is basically stealing money from his pocket. :) However, if you still intend to that, even I strongly disagree, I will try to expand the answer. Only because we live in the same coordinates :)

Comment: cant afford to be ethical rt nw :)... I'll go ahead with this... thanks.. waiting for ur edit...

Comment: I have started android programming 2 days back. If there's anything that is to be added in this code by me, I think your efforts will be in vain... I'll still try this...

Comment: and starting service is another option, just do not use activity.

Comment: and where am I declaring enableData?

Comment: Well, you have to register the connectivity change alarm even twice: one to enable, then to disable.

Comment: and what about registering the connectivity alarm twice?

Comment: Don't you want to register two events? One to enable, one to disable

Comment: btw, I am getting this - "Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front"...

Comment: ... that means the app you want to install has EXACTLY same code as the one from your device

Comment: yes, am getting this error in console and thats why I am unable to test my app: -
 [2013-11-13 15:36:33 - MobileData] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.sang.mobiledata/.MainActivity }
[2013-11-13 15:36:33 - MobileData] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: if I knew what to change, this discussion would have been over long before... :)

Comment: Dude, "greu de cap" comes from the deep of the mountains :P ... from above comment (if you consider reading all comments):  `that means the app you want to install has EXACTLY same code as the one from your device` ... So add two spaces anywhere in your code, save the Java file and re-install.

Comment: ya I got that after my comment :) ... ok, now how do you suggest I test it??

Comment: Start the app, start drinking until 10 PM, check then if the data connectivity is off, then if success, continue drinking until 6 AM and check then if connectivity is on. If so, I expect a beer pack too ... Or if you can't rise to this challenge, change the times above so the enabling and disabling are scheduled after 5 and 10 minutes your time. I don't want to hear you can't do it ...

Comment: I would say "Multzam fain" for an upvote :) ... I'm hunting some badges ;)

Comment: I think its working, I'll have to retest it though... Thanks for your gr8 efforts..!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to upvote... tried that already... n btw, the connection din't get back on @ 6:00.. so its not completely working... :)

Comment: Maybe because you're using reflection code ... I think you have enough reputation for a single upvote

Comment: requires 15 reputation points... I got 13.. will do it, dnt wry...
its not cause I am using reflection code but because in the onReceive I only have code to turn it off... I need to put the code to turn it on as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can set two alarms, one for 10pm and another for 6am, and then when the alarms trigger, system will start services for you to do your own works.

```
   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(
     this, YourOwnerService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```